# Taweez and my Husband

Tags: nikah, tawiz

I have been married from almost 2 years. My husband and I were having a good time but from previous few months my husband's behavior has changed. He says he does not love me and he is no more attracted towards me. There is no other woman in his life, he thinks someone did taweez on him to destroy our relationship. Sometimes suddenly he gets angry and then later he feels sorry for his behavior. He really cares about me.

He tries a lot to love me but he can't. And he thinks our marriage is gonna end up in divorce. And we both don't want divorce, we have a daughter.Is there any way to know if really he is under the action of some taweez because he wasn't like this before, and if he is how to remove the bad effect of that taweez.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE, take a [tour](http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the site better.

Comment: @Murtaza That does not help. The OP is probably very disturbed and making a tour is the last thing she would want to do.

Comment: The last two Surah of Quran (Al-Falaq and An-Nas) should be recited to break off effects of magic and Taweez. You can consult a scholar to more details.

Comment: Read in detail [Reality of Magic and It's Cure in Islam](http://allahu-ahad.org/r.php?p=magic.pdf). It may take time for u to finish reading this but it will in sha' Allah help you in detail. Hope this helps. Wassalām

Comment: Has your husband shared with you anything about his own thinking just before he gets angry? For example, is he himself thinking about something (for example something that someone else has done to him in the past) that makes him angry? It would be helpful for you to know if his anger is caused (or fueled) by his own thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe on such things on 2014; Assi7r (magic and voodoo stuff) and such.. It has to do with psychology and human nature.

You said your husband thinks he do not love you; then try to find why. Ask him about what made him love you in the beginning and what has changed? maybe it has to do with the daily routine of being together? maybe you have given all your love to the child and you forgot your husband? maybe it has to do with other small things; your cloths, your perfume (no kidding!) just talk to him and let yourself both speak sincere.

Love is like a rose; it needs to be aroused to stay alive.

Inchallah you solve it.

Comment: This doesn't give answer when you says you don't believe just because you live in modern word. Prove by providing reference of Ayah or Hadith.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote! My proof is why in modern-developed societies nobody suffers from Taweez (or whatever you call it) and nobody believes in such thing, well, except in the horror movies where we see cursed zombies and such.. Come on!

Comment: I said prove by mentioning ayah or hadith, just saying that I don't believe in such things, doesn't make sense. There are some people who still says there is no GOD because they can't see him so should we believe in them, defiantly not.

Comment: The point really is that the husband may be suffering from mental health issues, which requires medical attention. Do you really believe its magic/taweez on the husband? The answers below are all speculation and may cause more destruction.

Answer (score 1):

Don't wait for any one else. Just recite "Aozu Billahi main-shaytanir-rajeem". Pray regularly, recite Quran and try to understand it and act upon it. Further try to read the life and Sayings of Prophet Muhammad (SAW) and request Almighty for His Blessings and Mercies. Insha Allah the difference will be resolved if Almighty wills.

Answer (score 0):

Although sihir(magic) exists, it is impermissible in Islam to speculate such things.
This is not new and very common in every marriage. If every couple starts thinking it's taweez (magic) or bad eye then where does the affect of not performing good deeds go?
When someone stops or reduces the ibadah, Allah swt shows the effect of that in this life or the hereafter. You are lucky that you are seeing the effect of it here.

We often put blame on others or others' actions (taweez) but in reality have done nothing to correct our own wrongdoings.

Being extra courteous to one's spouse in the matters of difficulty is the first step towards making up with the partner. Increasing the prayer, zikr and doing things which both of you enjoy is a major step towards a better marriage.
The effects of taweez (if any) will go away when you both sit and recite Quran and learn it's meanings inshaAllah.

Also, if you or your husband are addicted to bollywood movies or TV serials, know that due to lack of censorship and vulgarity, the love towards ones husband or wife diminishes. 
It's best to spend the time creatively in halal entertainment.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -2):

Find the Taweez and destroy it, read your Kuls and pray to Allah SWT. Cause they can't do anything without the permission of Allah.